# how to get controlled random number in c#

Tags: c#, random

I want to generate random numbers but controlled, meaning the numbers should be nearly equally separated, and spread through the range.

As an example, if the bounds were 1 and 50, then if the first generated number is 40 then the next number should not be close.  Suppose it's 20, then 30 would be an acceptable third number.

Please help.

Comment: you'll have to define some rules in order to get code. Your Q does not do this. It might help if you state what you will do with these numbers.

Comment: How would it be random if there's a predictable pattern to it?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many numbers you will be generating?

Comment: infact i have uploaded a file and i want to publish it at random time,like if i select it to be published between 5-10 minutes. then there r possiblites dat 5 records are published between 8-10 minutes.

Comment: this comment makes the requirements less clear

Answer (score 5):

Rather than completely random numbers, you might want to look at noise functions like Perlin Noise to generate superficially random data in a predictable fashion.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

There are a few variations out there - definitely worth researching if you can describe your segmentation of data algorithmically.

It's used a lot in gaming to smooth and add interest to otherwise randomly generated terrain textures.

There's a few sample implementations in C# out there, this one is used to generate a bitmap but could easily be adapted to fill a 2d array:

> http://www.gutgames.com/post/Perlin-Noise.aspx

There's also plenty of questions here on SO about Perlin Noise too:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=perlin+noise

Answer (score 3):

You may do something like this:

```
randomSpaced[interval_, mindistance_, lastone_] :=
         (While[Abs[(new = RandomReal[interval])-lastone] < mindistance,];
          Return[new];)
```

Randomnicity test drive:

```
For[i = 1, i < 500000, i++,
  rnd[i] = randomSpaced[{0, 40}, 10, rnd[i - 1]];
  ];
Histogram[Table[rnd[i], {i, 500000}]]
```

[image]

**You may see that the frequencies accumulates in the borders**

Moreover, if you are not cautious, and ask for a distance too high, the results will be something like:

```
For[i = 1, i < 50000, i++, 
  AppendTo[rnd, randomSpaced[{0, 40}, 25, Last[rnd]]];];
   Histogram[rnd
```

]

[image]

because you are not allowing points at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Define a separation distance d the new number should have to the last. If the last number was, say, 20 the next random number should not be from 20-d to 20+d. That means the random interval should be [1, 20-d) and (20+d,50].

Since you can not call random.next() with two intervals you need to call it with an interval reduced by 2d and then map the random number to your original [1,50] interval.

```
static class RandomExcludingSurrounding
{
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static int Next(int x, int d, int min, int max)
    {
        int next = random.Next(min, max-2*d);
        if (next > x-d)
            next += 2*d;
        return next;
    }
}

int min = 1;
int max = 50;
Random random = new Random();
int next = random.Next(min, max);

while(true)
{
    int next = RandomExcludingSurrounding.Next(next, 20, min, max);
    Console.WriteLine(next);
}
```

Comment: That's how understood the question at first. But it's not what the OP needs.

Comment: @CodeInChaos We don't know what the OP is needing the random numbers for, if it is trivial getting into perlin noise is overkill.

Comment: don't new Random on every call! it will restart the seed base on DateTime.Now every time...

Comment: Fixed, thanks. The errors you make when you want to be brief.

Comment: Perlin Noise isn't *that* complex to implement - take a peek at the C# impl. for example - ~30 lines but I agree the OP needs to help us understand his use of the data, his last comment was a twist from his original Q.